# csquotes and foreignlanguages: setting the outer language for quotation marks

Tags: babel, languages, csquotes, quotation

The package csquotes defines the quotation marks from the *quoted* (=inner) language, not from the environning language.

How can one set the *outer* language for defining the quotation marks of `\foreignquote` and `\foreignblockcquote`?

Edit: I am looking for a way to have the quotation marks produced *before* the language switch and the reference (if any) *after* the language has been switched back.

An example with `\foreignquote`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,french,english]{article} 
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
   \usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} 
   \usepackage{babel} 
   \begin{document}     
   \selectlanguage{english}     In an English paper, 
   if I quote something that is in French, 
  I have guillemets: \foreignquote{french}{Ceci est en français.}       
  I am looking for \enquote{\selectlanguage{french}Ceci est en français.} 
  \end{document}
```

[image: Example with \foreignquote]

An example with `\foreignblockcquote`:

```
    \selectlanguage{english}    In an English paper, 
       if I quote something that is in French, 
\foreignblockcquote{french}{REF}{Ceci est en \enquote{français}.}
%      I have guillemets: \foreignblockcquote{french}{REF}{Ceci est en \enquote{français}}.}        
      I am looking for \blockcquote{REF}{\selectlanguage{french}Ceci est en \og français \fg.\selectlanguage{english}}
```

[image: Example with \foreignblockcquote]

Note: I put `\selectlanguage{english}` at the end of \blockcquote in order for the reference to be in the paper's main language, here English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not find an official interface on the `csquotes` side that lets you do this, but there are some internal macros that you can redefine to let `csquotes` first produce the quotation marks and only then switch the language.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,french,english]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}

\makeatletter
%  {<init>}{<endinit>}{<text>}
\long\def\csq@quote@i#1#2#3{%
  \csq@bqgroup\csq@oqopen@i#1#3#2\csq@qclose@i{}}
\long\def\csq@quote@ii#1#2#3{%
  \csq@bqgroup\csq@iqopen@i#1#3#2\csq@qclose@i{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  In an English paper, if I quote something that is in French,
  I have guillemets: \foreignquote{french}{Ceci est en français.}
  
  I am looking for \enquote{\selectlanguage{french}Ceci est en français.}
\end{document}
```

[image: I am looking for “Ceci est en français.”]

---

If you want to reset the quotation mark level so that the foreign-language quotes start at the outer level, you need to dig a bit deeper.

The following solution should also address most block language switching commands.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,french,english]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\newcount\saved@csq@qlevel

\newcommand*{\tcsq@saveandreset@qlevel}{%
  \saved@csq@qlevel\csq@qlevel
  \csq@qlevel\z@}
  
\newcommand*{\tcsq@restore@qlevel}{%
  \csq@qlevel\saved@csq@qlevel}

%  {<init>}{<endinit>}{<text>}
\long\def\csq@quote@i#1#2#3{%
  \csq@bqgroup\csq@oqopen@i#1#3#2\csq@qclose@i{}}
\long\def\csq@quote@ii#1#2#3{%
  \csq@bqgroup\csq@iqopen@i#1#3#2\csq@qclose@i{}}


\def\csq@fquote@i#1{\csq@quote@i{\csq@lang{#1}\tcsq@saveandreset@qlevel}{\tcsq@restore@qlevel\csq@endlang}}
\def\csq@fquote@ii#1{\csq@quote@ii{\csq@lang{#1}\tcsq@saveandreset@qlevel}{\tcsq@restore@qlevel\csq@endlang}}
\def\csq@hquote@i#1{\csq@quote@i{\csq@hyph{#1}\tcsq@saveandreset@qlevel}{\tcsq@restore@qlevel\csq@endhyph}}
\def\csq@hquote@ii#1{\csq@quote@ii{\csq@hyph{#1}\tcsq@saveandreset@qlevel}{\tcsq@restore@qlevel\csq@endhyph}}

% {<init>}{<endinit>}{<qopen>}{<citehook>}{<cite>}{<punct>}{<text>}{<apunct>}<tpunct>
\long\def\csq@tquote@i#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{%
  \begingroup
  \csq@setsfcodes
  \edef\csq@tempa{%
    \unexpanded{%
      \mktextquote
      {#3}%
      {#1#7}%
      {#2\csq@qclose@i{}}%
      {#6}{#8}}%
    {\ifblank{#5}
       {}
       {\unexpanded{\csq@switchlang{#4{#5}}}}}}%
  \csq@bqgroup\csq@tempa#9%
  \endgroup}

\def\csq@ftquote@i#1{%
  \csq@getcargs{\csq@tquote
    {\csq@lang{#1}\tcsq@saveandreset@qlevel}{\tcsq@restore@qlevel\csq@endlang}
    {\csq@oqopen@i}}}
\def\csq@ftquote@ii#1{%
  \csq@getcargs{\csq@tquote
    {\csq@lang{#1}\tcsq@saveandreset@qlevel}{\tcsq@restore@qlevel\csq@endlang}
    {\csq@iqopen@i}}}

\def\csq@htquote@i#1{%
  \csq@getcargs{\csq@tquote
    {\csq@hyph{#1}\tcsq@saveandreset@qlevel}{\tcsq@restore@qlevel\csq@endhyph}
    {\csq@oqopen@i}}}
\def\csq@htquote@ii#1{%
  \csq@getcargs{\csq@tquote
    {\csq@hyph{#1}\tcsq@saveandreset@qlevel}{\tcsq@restore@qlevel\csq@endhyph}
    {\csq@iqopen@i}}}

\def\csq@ftcquote@i#1{%
  \csq@getccargs{\csq@tquote
    {\csq@lang{#1}\tcsq@saveandreset@qlevel}{\tcsq@restore@qlevel\csq@endlang}
    {\csq@oqopen@i}}}
\def\csq@ftcquote@ii#1{%
  \csq@getccargs{\csq@tquote
    {\csq@lang{#1}\tcsq@saveandreset@qlevel}{\tcsq@restore@qlevel\csq@endlang}
    {\csq@iqopen@i}}}
  
\def\csq@htcquote@i#1{%
  \csq@getccargs{\csq@tquote
    {\csq@hyph{#1}\tcsq@saveandreset@qlevel}{\tcsq@restore@qlevel\csq@endhyph}
    {\csq@oqopen@i}}}
\def\csq@htcquote@ii#1{%
  \csq@getccargs{\csq@tquote
    {\csq@hyph{#1}\tcsq@saveandreset@qlevel}{\tcsq@restore@qlevel\csq@endhyph}
    {\csq@iqopen@i}}}

% {<init>}{<endinit>}{<citehook>}{<cite>}{<punct>}{<text>}{<apunct>}<tpunct>

\def\csq@bquote@ii#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{\csq@tquote@i{}{}{\csq@oqopen@i}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#1#6#2}{#7}{#8}}

% {<init>}{<endinit>}{<citehook>}{<cite>}{<punct>}{<text>}{<apunct>}<tpunct>

\long\def\csq@bquote@iii#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{%
  \begin{\csq@blockenvironment}%
  \toggletrue{csq@block}%
  \csq@setsfcodes
  \edef\csq@tempa{%
    \unexpanded{%
      \mkblockquote
      {#1#6}%
      {#5}{#7}}%
    {#2\ifblank{#4}
       {}
       {\unexpanded{\csq@switchlang{#3{#4}}}}}}%
  \csq@tempa#8%
  \end{\csq@blockenvironment}}

\renewrobustcmd*{\foreignblockquote}[1]{%
  \csq@getcargs{\csq@bquote{\csq@lang{#1}\tcsq@saveandreset@qlevel}{\tcsq@restore@qlevel\csq@endlang}}}

\renewrobustcmd*{\hyphenblockquote}[1]{%
  \csq@getcargs{\csq@bquote{\csq@hyph{#1}\tcsq@saveandreset@qlevel}{\tcsq@restore@qlevel\csq@endhyph}}}

\renewrobustcmd*{\hybridblockquote}[1]{%
  \csq@getcargs{%
    \csq@bquote
      {\iftoggle{csq@block}{\csq@lang}{\csq@hyph}{#1}\tcsq@saveandreset@qlevel}
      {\tcsq@restore@qlevel\iftoggle{csq@block}{\csq@endlang}{\csq@endhyph}}}}

\renewrobustcmd*{\foreignblockcquote}[1]{%
  \csq@getccargs{\csq@bquote{\csq@lang{#1}\tcsq@saveandreset@qlevel}{\tcsq@restore@qlevel\csq@endlang}}}

\renewrobustcmd*{\hyphenblockcquote}[1]{%
  \csq@getccargs{\csq@bquote{\csq@hyph{#1}\tcsq@saveandreset@qlevel}{\tcsq@restore@qlevel\csq@endhyph}}}

\renewrobustcmd*{\hybridblockcquote}[1]{%
  \csq@getccargs{%
    \csq@bquote
      {\iftoggle{csq@block}{\csq@lang}{\csq@hyph}{#1}\tcsq@saveandreset@qlevel}
      {\tcsq@restore@qlevel\iftoggle{csq@block}{\csq@endlang}{\csq@endhyph}}}}
\makeatother

\SetCiteCommand{\autocite}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  Lorem \foreignquote{french}{Ceci est en français.}
  
  Lorem \foreignquote{french}{Ceci \enquote{\enquote{est} en} français.}
  
  Lorem \foreigntextquote{french}{Ceci \enquote{\enquote{est} en} français.}
  
  Lorem \foreignblockcquote{french}{sigfridsson}{Ceci est en \enquote{français}.}
  
  Lorem \foreignblockcquote{french}{sigfridsson}{Ceci est en \enquote{français}. \lipsum}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for: produce the quotation marks in the defined language and then switch to the quoted language. Your solution works for \foreignquote if there is no embedded \enquote in it: \foreignquote{french}{Ceci est en \enquote{français}} produces English quotation marks for \enquote. I edited my question to introduce a variant I am looking for with \foreignblockcquote, which with your solution produces French guillemets outside and English quotation marks inside the quote.

Comment: @Tecti The solution also works if you have an `\enquote` inside a `\foreignquote`. But you get the quotation marks for the inner nesting level (which for the default French style are English-style marks; you can test with German to see that there is indeed a switch to the quotation marks of the other language). I guess you could reset the counter when you do language switching so you start at outer French quotation marks, but that probably requires some fiddling.

Comment: Indeed, it works with \foreignquote. But not with \foreignblockcquote when the quoted part is small (inline quote).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly this should be enough:

```
\DeclareQuoteStyle{french}
  {\textquotedblleft}
  {\textquotedblright}
  {\textquoteleft}
  {\textquoteright}
```

You can change the inner quotation marks to «...» with this:

```
\DeclareQuoteStyle{french}
  {\textquotedblleft}
  {\textquotedblright}
  {\guillemotleft}
  {\guillemotright}
```

So that this code

```
 \foreignquote{french}{Ceci est en français: \enquote{Il l'a dit}}
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: The problem is not to change the style of the quotes themselves. This answer would prevent having embedded quotations, such as  \foreignquote{french}{Ceci est en français: \enquote{Il l'a dit}.}   I would then want the embedded quotes to be French guillemets (the style of the surrounding language, ie French here).

Comment: I still don't understand what result you want to achieve. Perhaps a few more examples would help. I added a variation to the code above, in response to your comment